# Android get notification color in API < 21

Tags: android, notifications

How can I get the color of one noitification icon, at API < 21.
I know that in API >=21 I can do: `notification.color`
But I dont know how to get the color on API < 21.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no notification color prior to API Level 21, AFAIK. Also, `color` is not related to the icon.